# Addition of two numbers

Tags: c

I need help to solve a really simple problem. I wrote code that adds two numbers, but only in type `float`. So when I write `2+2`, it gives me `4.0`. What do I need to do in order to get only `4`? But in the same time if I write `5.2+5.3` to get `10.5`?

It's homework, and should not include an `if` statement.

I tried all variable types, but it just gives me unrealistic numbers. I would really appreciate if someone helped.

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*Addition of two numbers*/

 int main()
{
    float a;
    float b;
    float x;

   printf("Enter the first number:\n");
   scanf("%f", &a);

   printf("Enter the second number:\n");
   scanf("%f", &b);

   x = a + b;

   /*Printing decimal number*/

   printf("Result: %.1f + %.1f = %.1f", a, b, x);

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: What is the exactly issue you are running into?  It looks OK to me.

Comment: `printf("Result: %d", (int)x);`

Comment: make x of type "int" and use %d for x in the printf statement.

Comment: The `%g` formater is what you want: `printf("Result: %g + %g = %g", a, b, x);`

Comment: @sramij Tried it, but then it does not work on decimal numbers. I need both to work.

Comment: Not directly relevant: The return type of `main()` should be `int`, not `float`.

Comment: @Azeem Well, he was not allowed to use ints. :D

Comment: @Adrian The first one works just fine for me, but what is the second one if you do not mind explaining?

Comment: @newya Do you want the shortest/simplest output (as the given answer does), or do you want to 'reflect' the precision given in the input? Maybe my example was confusing: How about if input is (as in your pre-edit post) `5.5` and `5.5`? Do you want to output `11` or `11.0` (the latter reflecting input precision)?

Comment: @Adrian Oh, sorry, didn't understand the first time you asked. I want to output `11` . 
Wouldn't I just use `%.1f` if I wanted to output `11.0` ?

Comment: Or, how about inputs of `5.35` and `5.65`? Then, you would need %.2f?

Comment: @Adrian True! So what would be the smartest code to write in this situation?

Comment: OK, Like I said, it's tricky. For inputs with non-zero fractions, that's one thing; for inputs like `5.000`, to "spot" that there's a 3-dp precision is difficult using functions like `scanf`. I'm "otherwise engaged" right now, but I'll try to get some code for the 'non-zero' fractions posted. (Others are welcome to "beat me to it" though!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200399/discussion-between-newya-and-adrian).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to use the `g` format specifier for the `printf` instruction. This is used for printing the shortest representation. You can read more about format specifiers here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

This code prints how you described: `5 + 5 = 10` and `5.1 + 5.2 = 10.3`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int  main()
{
  float a;
  float b;
  float x;

  printf("Enter the first number:\n");
  scanf("%f", &a);

  printf("Enter the second number:\n");
  scanf("%f", &b);

  x = a + b;

  /*Printing decimal number*/

  printf("Result: %.1f + %.1f = %g\n", a, b, x);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Skip the return statement. It fills no purpose.

Comment: @klutt There's nothing wrong with making the return from `main` explicit, rather than relying on special-case behavior for that function.  The generated code should be identical.

Comment: @TomKarzes It's nothing "wrong" per se. It just don't fill any purpose whatsoever. It just clutters the code.

Comment: @klutt Most people would disagree with that. Implicit return values are generally not something you want to rely on, and the only reason it's even allowed in C is to support legacy code. Otherwise, why is it only supported for `main` and not every other `int`-valued function?

Comment: @TomKarzes I have a very hard time believing it is to support legacy code, because prior to C99, a return statement was *required* in `main` according to the standard. In C90 it was UB. If I have to guess, I'd say that it's allowed for main because when it comes to main it ALWAYS means the exit status (unless you decide to do something controversial), which is not something you can say for int-valued functions in general.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be 'smart' (and I use that term loosely, rather than advisedly - and neither am I trying to detract anything from the great answer posted by @Sebi), and format your output according to the (maximum) precision of the input(s), then this will work for 'fractional' parts that aren't zero:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a, b, x, test;
    int aPrec = 0, bPrec = 0, xPrec = 0, iTest;

    printf("Enter the first number:\n");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    test = (float)fabs(a); // Just in case it's -ve!
    iTest = (int)(test + 0.5);
    while (test != (float)(iTest)) {
        ++aPrec;
        test *= 10.0;
        iTest = (int)(test + 0.5);
    }

    printf("Enter the second number:\n");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    test = (float)fabs(b); // Just in case it's -ve!
    iTest = (int)(test + 0.5);
    while (test != (float)(iTest)) {
        ++bPrec;
        test *= 10.0;
        iTest = (int)(test + 0.5);
    }

    x = a + b;
    xPrec = aPrec > bPrec ? aPrec : bPrec; // Or, you could use max()!!
    // The "*" precision specifiers get their values from arguments immediately …
    /// … preceding the relevant 'float' value!
    printf("Result: %.*f + %.*f = %.*f", aPrec, a, bPrec, b, xPrec, x);
    return 0;
}
```

What the code is doing, is to keep multiplying each input by `10` until it sees that this 'test' value is then equal to its integral (truncated) value; this is the "precision" value for each input, `a` and `b`. Now, being `smart` (again, I use the term loosely), it thinks that the output precision should be the greater of the two inputs.

If you don't know how the `"%.*f` format specifier works, I can add more details, of course.

Comment: OK, so why the downvote? I care, really! (And not just for the rep ... if I'm posting rubbish, which I never would deliberately, then please tell me why you think I am!)